# ¿Pueden ir las etiquetas <meta> fuera del <head> (Dentro del <body>)?

Tags: html5, seo

Tengo un script en `php` que muestra contenido dentro del `<body>` y que extrae de la base de datos una columna de descripción entonces yo quería poner de manera dinámica el texto de esa descripción dentro del content de la etiqueta `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>` ¿Será válido para el SEO que esta se encuentre fuera del `<head>`

Comment: Para el SEO, obviamente que no, pero a nivel programador tampoco está mal.